# Postgresql jsonb vs datetime

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I need to store two dates valid_from, and valid_to.

Is it better to use two datetime fields like valid_from:datetime and valid_to:datatime.

Would be it better to store data in jsonb field validity: `{"from": "2001-01-01", "to": "2001-02-02"}`

Much more reads than writes to database.
DB: PostgresSQL 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `daterange` type :
ie :

- `'[2001-01-01, 2001-02-02]'::daterange` means from `2001-01-01` to `2001-02-02`
  bound inclusive
- `'(2001-01-01, 2001-02-05)'::daterange` means from `2001-01-01`
  to `2001-02-05` bound exclusive

Also :

- Special value like `Infinite` can be use
- `lower(anyrange)` => lower bound of range
- and many other things like overlap operator, see the docs ;-)

[Range Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

Comment: `id |         name          | place  |        validity`
`----+-----------------------+--------+-------------------------`
`  1 | 100% Responsive       | top    | [2001-01-02,2020-01-01)`
`  3 | Beautyfull Typography | top    | [2001-01-02,2021-01-01)`

How to find rows where date 2021-01-01 is inclusive in validity?
I need row id 3 with given date 2021-01-01.

Comment: in `[2001-01-02,2021-01-01)` ==> 2021-01-01 is exluded

Comment: in `[2001-01-02,2021-01-01]` ==> 2021-01-01 is included

Comment: `validity @> '2021-01-01'::date ` select validity range containg 2021-01-01

Answer (score 1):

Use two `timestamp` columns (there is no `datetime` type in Postgres).

They can efficiently be indexed and they protect you from invalid timestamp values  - nothing prevents you from storing `"2019-02-31 28:99:00"` in a JSON value.

If you very often need to use those two values to check if another tiemstamp values lies in between, you could also consider a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) that stores both values in a single column.